# base64 string more than 10kb is not uploading on server, getting 500 error in laravel in windos server

Tags: json, iis, base64, laravel-8, http-status-code-500

Getting 500 error when trying to upload base64 image string size more than 10kb. It's working fine on my local machine but not working of server.

Here is the configuration:

```
post_max_size :800M
max_file_uploads:200
max_input_time:600
max_input_vars:1000
memory_limit:1280M
```

Here are my parameters:

```
{"addedOn": "2021-07-07 08:35:45",
"api_token": "KeWgH8afLCCYudJSavZiEltZQKc0dU8i5Lncag7IqK9eV7SFtX4SHeIbZG0p",
"buildingId": "5",
"chunkCount": 0,
"fileId": 0,
"fileName": "lake-tekapo-new-zealand-hd-wallpaper_trey-ratcliff.jpg",
"isActive": true,
"size": 2097152,
"totalSize": 4993938,
"fileData":"base-64 string"
}
```

Comment: More than 10kb is weird as I know the default is always 2M. The issue is with your server, check you are editing the correct php.ini file sometimes its the fpm's ini that is loaded. you can check this by phpinfo() in your index.blade

Comment: I am facing the same issue max 10kb allowing

Answer (score 0):

You can try to increase the file upload limit in iis:

1. Open IIS Manager, Select the website that you want to configure.
2. Make sure you are in Features View per the button at the bottom of the manager.
3. Select Requests Filtering and open it by double-clicking the icon. The Request Filtering pane displays.
4. From the Actions pane on the right hand side of the screen click Edit Feature Settings... link. The Edit Request Filtering Settings window displays.
5. In the Request Limits section, enter the appropriate Maximum allowed content length (Bytes) and then click the OK button.
6. Restart IIS.